# .htaccess will not redirect .php files

Tags: mod-rewrite

I have this in my htaccess, standard domain redirection:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/fullnewdomain\.org\/$1" [QSA,R=301,L]
```

And it works fine for folders, subfolders, html files, images, etc. However, for some reason it refuses to redirect php files. Instead they still run as normal and do not redirect to the new domain. Any ideas as to why, and how I can fix it? It's almost like this host is trying to execute the php file before checking any rules ( And I'm not sure what I could do if that's the case! ).

Comment: Strange. Rewrite rules _are_ applied before PHP is run, if it's an Apache module. I can't _promise_ you that the same is true when PHP is run as CGI... as I've never tried it; though I'd be amazed if it weren't.

Comment: What did your host say about this?

Comment: Well hosts don't talk they are servers...

Comment: Are there any other lines in your .htaccess file? These rules are processed before the Apache executes the file, since the rules can tell Apache which file to execute. I suspect there may be another rule that executes first and causes this redirection not to happen, such as a rule that removes the .php from the filename or that changes the extension.

Comment: No extra rules exist. I've filed a ticket with the host ( Hostgator, for future reference ) to see what's up. Did some digging and it happens with every php file and any redirects for any domain I have here, so I'm really starting to think this is a server issue specific to them.

Comment: just curious, why do u have quotes for new domain in the RewriteRule?

Comment: I'd clean up the `"http\:\/\/fullnewdomain\.org\/$1"` to `http://fullnewdomain.org/$1` first. If it still doesn't work, enabling a `RewriteLog` may shed some light on it.

Comment: @user1190992 apparently the host prefers them be quoted and properly escaped ( The format they put them in when using their redirection "tool" ) so I just followed their lead in my hand-written ones. Same effect with or without, so it doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: @Wrikken this is shared hosting, I can't add anything to apache's config

Comment: This is not _"properly escaped"_, this is ... misguidedly escaped. But if changing it doesn't work (if no other rules are active, it should), they probably have some rules in the config that you can't access that either stop or prohibit rewriting php files. So yeah, filing the ticket & let them fix it is then your only option.

Comment: According to the cheatsheet, http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/download/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet-v2.png ... the only difference I found that you have the QSA flag.Some support from the host provider might help ..

Comment: Try clearing your browsers cache, and recheck that the static resources still get redirected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was an htaccess file the host had placed in the home directory ( One level above public_html ) to "counter" bots, but all it did was break anything else that tried to apply a rule to php files. Removed the file, problem solved itself.

For reference, hostgator was the host, and I still don't know why they felt the need to place the file there in the first place.